# Running a local script on local host with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a python script which is able to retrieve the IP adress of my remote node, and as a pre-task of my ansible playbook I would like to run this script and set the IP adress. Is there a command in Ansible which would allow me to do this ?

Comment: `delegate_to: localhost` along with `set_fact` should do the trick. For more details, more information about the script is needed.

Answer (score 1):

With *delegate_to* it is possible to control where an action is run.

Straight from the Ansible documentation:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  serial: 5

  tasks:
    - name: Take out of load balancer pool
      ansible.builtin.command: /usr/bin/take_out_of_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

This will run the command on the ansible host.
There is really not much more to it!

Link to
[Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can

```
- name: Run local script
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Execute script
      command: /path/to/your/script.py
      register: script_output

    - name: Print script output
      debug:
        var: script_output.stdout
```

or as proxx mentioned, u can use *delegate_to*

```
- name: Run local script on remote host
  hosts: your_remote_node
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Execute script on control machine
      command: /path/to/your/script.py
      register: script_output
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Print script output
      debug:
        var: script_output.stdout
```